# Save SNMP return values in MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, net-snmp

I used this `snmpwalk` function to fetch all the SNMP objects.

```
<?php
$a = snmpwalk("127.0.0.1", "public", ""); 

foreach ($a as $val) {
    echo "$val\n";
}

?>
```

It works correctly, but the retrieved information has a complex format.

Now I want to save the response in a MySQL database.
I haven't any idea about how to do that.

Comment: use** insert** query inside foreach or creat array and insert value in database

Comment: It is not possible because it is in very complex format. As a example

Comment: SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (586998396) 67 days, 22:33:03.96
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = net-snmp
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = UCDavis
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.1 = OID: SNMPv2-MIB::snmpMIB
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.2 = OID: IF-MIB::ifMIB
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.4 = OID: IP-MIB::ip
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.5 = OID: UDP-MIB::udpMIB

Comment: you cal save all data as **longtext** format in database

Comment: As described at http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpwalk.html If no OID argument is present, snmpwalk will search the subtree rooted at SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2 Do you really need that whole sub-tree or can you be more specific (for faster retrieval, less data to store and simpler data to parse) ?